# Remove all vowels from a file name using shell script

Tags: file, shell, rename

Current code:

```
find . -depth | \
while read LONG; do
    SHORT=$( basename "$LONG" | tr '[aeiou]' '[ ]' )
    DIR=$( dirname "$LONG" )
    if [ "${LONG}" != "${DIR}/${SHORT}" ]; then
            mv "${LONG}" "${DIR}/${SHORT}"
    fi
done
```

So if I have files like aaa abc bdf I get the files '   ' ' bc' 'bdf'

The way I want this to work is to return 'aaa' 'bc' bdf'.
(Completly remove the a from the second file and if all the characters (excluding the file extension) are vowels, ignore it.

Comment: What have you got against vowels??? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the two problems with your solution are:

- You're substituting vowels for a space.  Shouldn't you substitute an empty string?
- Then you need to test if SHORT is empty.  If it is, discard it, perhaps by assigning SHORT=LONG.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all vowels:

```
tr -d aeiou
```

Ignore if basename (excluding the file extension) is only vowels:

```
case $SHORT in ''|.*) continue;; esac
```